# How to complete the three Queue implementations as well as the three Stack implementations?

Tags: java

How would I fix this issue?
I've completed the code but the only issue is that it keeps saying the variable cannot be found. For these listed below:

QueueArrayBased pQueue = new QueueArrayBased();
        StackArrayBased pStack = new StackArrayBased();

I've already checked the naming which is identical to the class being called. I don't know what else to do. Please help I would greatly appreciate it. I have import java.util.*; because a source said that it would fix that issue and it didn't.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class isPalindrome
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Word to check: ");

        String userInput = sc.nextLine();
        userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
        System.out.print(isPal(userInput)+"  ");


    }

    public static boolean isPal(String str)
    {
        QueueArrayBased pQueue = new QueueArrayBased();
        StackArrayBased pStack = new StackArrayBased();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            pQueue.enqueue(str.charAt(i));
            pStack.push(str.charAt(i));
        }

        //start to compare

        while(!pQueue.isEmpty())
        {
            if(pQueue.dequeue() != pStack.pop()){
                return false;
            }
        }

        //finished w/ empty queue (and empty stack)

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you expect them _not_ to produce an error? There's no definition or import of those two classes.  The java compiler has no idea what they are.

Comment: So I have to import those classes like this: import QueueArrayBased.*; if so i tried it and it didn't work. If not how do you mean? @Gene

Answer (score 0):

You said you've implemented the classes already, so if you're getting this sort of error, your class must be in a different package. When you write a class in a different package from the one in which you want to use it, you have to `import` it into your current Java file. For example, if your `QueueArrayBased` and `StackArrayBased` classes are in a package called "structures," you would include `import structures.QueueArrayBased` and `import structures.StackArrayBased` (or just `import structures.*` to get both at once) among your `import` statements. Then, you can use the class freely.

I would recommend reviewing some Java project structure before moving on much farther. It'll make your life easier down the road. You can find a good explanation on packages and imports [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/packages-in-java/).